# Can I use URL routes with both backend API and Web front end like Backbone.js?

Tags: api, rest, backbone.js, routes

I am completely confused by the notion of the use of URL for routing and just don't understand if there is a conflict between the two concepts as I see them, or what I should do to prepare my development to using them.

The two concepts are URL routing to determine front end rendering (à la backbone.js) and back-end routing as a means to provide an API service. The conflict is if they are on the same domain.

For example let's say I plan Front End routing like this:
A framework such as backbone.js uses routing in order to determine which actions to perform to render templates to the user. For example a url `http://www.mydomain.com/categories` is the route to render a list of categories in a template.

Howeever, it needs to get the list of categories from a backend service on the same domain in order to populate the model and handle changes to data. So I plan to be able to POST, UPDATE, DELETE etc...

So this is where I get confused. If I create a API service on `http://www.mydomain.com/managecategories` how does the front end framework know not to throw an error because I haven't defined that route?

And further what am expected to deal with (in terms of error handling or not) if I was just to update the URL manually and hit enter?

I just can't get my head round this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No conflict. No worries. Feel free.

Basically Backbone routing is mainly about how to change the url showing on browser address bar, how to respond to the changes, and how to respond to existing url etc. They are all front-end things, **no request will be sent to server**.

On the other hind, for the sync urls in collection/model, they are real urls that **will send requests to sever** at JSON format(or JS/HTML). Normally there is a jQuery `$.ajax` method behind these urls.

So, they are two totally different things. Feel free to do whatever you like, there will be no conflict at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to provide [url of the models](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) (categories in your case) and/or [url of collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) if you plan to fetch them.

Routing inside of the [Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes) is a totally different concept and affects what views should get initialized

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I'm not asking where to put the URLs, I'm asking what happens for the user if they type in a URL that is not specified in the Router, but is a valid URL for the service.

Comment: Well, your router should have a fallback case for cases that do not match any pattern. For example:
` routes: {
  "dashboard"                 : "dashboard",
  "search/:q"                 : "search",
  "*path"                     : "other"
 },`

Comment: OK so this throws an error when the user types it in the address bar. But what if the Model or Collection executes this request at this error throwing URL as well?